# How to pinch and zoom the images separetly in a scrollview in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

I am having different images in my scroll view and I need to make pinching and zooming for each object seperately.Can any one suggest me how to do this??

I used viewForZooming but it only applicable for the image I lastly added to the scrollview.

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing scrollable/zoomable views on another scrollable/zoomable view (like `UIScrollView`) is not a good idea IMHO (i.e. if superview can cancel content touches than it probably will be difficult to zoom images. If superview can't cancel content touches than you'll have troubles with scrolling).

You can implement something like multi-page view (and implement page changing with swype gesture, for example), every page of which has a number of zoomable images (placed on their own `UIScrollView`s)